# Cannot get reply from recruiter

Tags: job-search, recruitment, email, linkedin

I sent a job application to company X a month ago. This is a big global company with thousands of employees and currently hundreds of job vacancies.

10 days ago I got a reply like this:

> Thanks for your interest in an opportunity here at Company X! I'm on
>   the recruiting team and would love to find time for us to connect in
>   the next week or so.
>
> When are you available for a 10 minute call?
>
> Looking forward to hearing from you!
>
> Mr Recruiter

So I replied to this from my email inbox but the email bounced as it was sent from `donotreply@companyx.com`

Confused I got the recruiter on LinkedIn and messaged them there.

I give it a few days and, Mr Recruiter doesn't accept my LinkedIn message or reply to it.

From the header of the original email I can see that Company X used `CompanyX@myworkday.com`. So I try to reply to that email address instead. That was 4 days ago and I've not heard anything back.

I really don't know what to do next. How else can I get in contact with this Recruiter who said they wanted to talk with me this week. It's maddening.

Comment: `I send a job application to companyX a month ago.` How did you do that? Over email or a job portal of the company?

Comment: Via a web portal set up by the company.

Answer (score 1):

It does not seem a situation that an organization would like their applicant to be in. However, we cannot rule out the possibility that this is because of a human error, the person from the recruiting team mistakenly used a no-reply mailer instead of their personal inbox to compose and send out the email.

In the current situation, you can do the following things:

- Check the portal you used for making the application for any "Contact Us" link or a phone number. Also, re-read the job description, sometimes it contains the pointers to be able to find a contact in the organization, at least.
- Scan the email you received for the presence of any other generic company correspondence mail ID or web page from where you can get a phone number /contact and get in touch about any update.
- Wait for the recruiter to realize their mistake, and get in touch with you.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't get the job.

Move on (mentally and emotionally).

The vast majority of recruiters would be all over you if there was a possibility of you having done so (and their getting commission).

> I give it a few days and, Mr Recruiter doesn't accept my LinkedIn
>   message or reply to it.

Send an email requesting an update, but don't get your hopes up.

> How else can I get in contact with this Recruiter who said they wanted
>   to talk with me this week. It's maddening.

You don't, except sending a chase email. They submitted other candidates, along with other recruiters and likely one/some of these have been contacted for followup.

Comment: Recruiters would be all over him, HR is a very different story.